# Access Ubuntu server from windows pc

Tags: gui, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a server with `ubuntu` installed. I can access its terminal with putty. Is it possible to access my server with windows remote desktop connection without installing any `gui` packages in my server. I want my server with minimum or no `gui`.

Thank you

Comment: If terminal access is not enough, and you do not want to install GUI in your server, you could install an Xserver on your windows machine (e.g. through `cygwin`package), allow X tunneling through ssh, and then start your applications on the server from your ssh session; this should display the window on your Windows PC.

Comment: Another solution with (minimal) GUI installation is by using [X2Go](http://wiki.x2go.org/). There is some more information in [Running a lightweight GUI](https://vpsboard.com/threads/running-a-lightweight-gui-on-your-vps-via-x2go.4241/). Look at the whole discussion there.

Comment: For putty/cygwin, see http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/putty-cygwin-tutorial.pdf or for more information on cygwin/X https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.pdf